# Unable to read multiple sql rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for days and i can't find what is wrong with this.

I am trying to get the top users with the highest aproved number from the ranks table

```
SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY  cast(Aprovados  as unsigned) DESC LIMIT 10
```

This query works on the phpmyadmin page, i get the result that i am looking for

I am trying this in php like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY cast(Aprovados  as unsigned) DESC LIMIT 10"); 
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo $row['Nome'];
             }
```

I get no result's

When i run this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;}
```

I get no rows found, i don't understand why, i think my query is ok because it works on the server the $con i think is also good i can use it to get single rows with no problems

I searched alot and this is the must common awnser [How to select multiple rows from mysql with one query and use them in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481806/how-to-select-multiple-rows-from-mysql-with-one-query-and-use-them-in-php)

Comment: you seem to be mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions throughout your code

Comment: omg, you are right, it works now, i can't believe i spent 2 days trying find this simple mistake, i used to get error messages on my old server about the mysql_ but on the new one i get nothing, once again thanks a lot :D

Comment: you can turn errors on yourself